# Fastest way to create 50 VM Clones in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

For test purposes, we would like to create 50 clones from a single master.  In general, what would be the fastest, simplest way to do this?

Comment: One could easily create a script file that does a file copy operation then runs the Virtual Box tool to change the UID of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `vboxmanage` command line tool in a script to clone the VM:

```
vboxmanage clonevm <Name of VM> --name <New Name> --register
```

Just use a script to run this 50 times.

Comment: cool, will try this!  What kind of script language would you suggest using?

Comment: I would just use  your OS's default shell scripting language, so a batch file on Windows or bash or similar on Unix/Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I started my script out with:

```
SET BOXNAME={master box}

"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" snapshot %BOXNAME% delete Snapshot
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" snapshot %BOXNAME% take Snapshot
```

It sets a variable equal to the name of the virtualbox i'm cloning (mine is in quotes), then deletes a snapshot named "Snapshot" if it exists and then makes a fresh one.  The snapshot names are case sensitive.

Then after that, you put as many of these lines as you need:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevm %BOXNAME% --snapshot Snapshot --basefolder "V:\vpn" --options link --name {NewBoxName} --register
```

- --snapshot:  this tells it what snapshot to use.  It's required if you're making linked clones.
- --options link:  Telling it to make linked clones
- --basefolder: This is telling it what folder you want it to store the files in. (optional)
- --name:  Plain text, no brackets or quotes... This is what you want to name your new box. You need to give each one a unique name, so if
  you're cloning it multiple times you need to edit each line to have a
  different name
- --register: not sure what this does.  All other tutorials have it...

I end mine with a pause so I can see if it worked.  Only thing that bothers me is that I can't figure out how to tell it where to put the virtualboxes in the folder structure inside the virtualbox manager.  I have to move them all, one at a time, to the folder I want to store them in.

Example from mine:

```
SET BOXNAME="VPNBox-Master"

"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" snapshot %BOXNAME% delete Snapshot
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" snapshot %BOXNAME% take Snapshot

"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevm %BOXNAME% --snapshot Snapshot --basefolder "V:\vpn" --options link --name VPNBox1 --register
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonevm %BOXNAME% --snapshot Snapshot --basefolder "V:\vpn" --options link --name VPNBox2 --register
pause
```